# Plugins rewrite rules not saved

Tags: wordpress

So I'm not sure if I'm not understanding how rewrite rules should work or not.  I would like to a number of links such as example.com/clubA and example.com/clubB that redirect to example.com/venue-details/clubA  where venue-details is a page.

The following code more or less does this:

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter('init','flushRules');
function flushRules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);
}
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
  $newrules = array();
// NB plan is to eventually loop through a DB table to generate rules for lots of clubs / venues.
    $newrules['clubA'] = 'index.php?pagename=venue-details';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

Now what I was expecting was that ones the rules had been generated they would be permanently saved/cached so that generating the rules wouldn't be needed for every page load.  for example, add the rules when your plugin is activated, set and forget.  But whatever I do they never stick around?

Is my expectation wrong and if not, how would I accomplish the persistence of rules?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Hooking the init action `add_filter('init','flushRules');` will lead to the rewrite rules being flushed with every page load.

Instead you should call `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules` once, when your plugin is installed, by using the following:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'flushRules');
```

Remove the second filter hook and still keep the first filter hook, you already have:

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
```

That will lead to the custom rewrite rules being generated, when your activation function is called and also if some other plugin or an admin flushes the rewrite rules.

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'flushRules');

function flushRules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(FALSE);
}
function my_insert_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    // NB plan is to eventually loop through a DB table to generate rules for lots of clubs / venues.
    $rules['clubA'] = 'index.php?pagename=venue-details';
    return $rules;
}
```